# read standard input from web server

Tags: c, cgi

I want to process POST data in a C CGI program on LINUX (SLES64)

In a first step I get the HTTP header with the content length.

Now I want to read the POST data from standard input.

I want to read AT MOST 5000 bytes of cgi data. Every POST with more is ignored!

```
number_of_bytes_read = read(0, buffer, content_length);
```

Now there is one particular case:

A user fills in a form in a browser and then he clicks submit.

An apache web server receives the request headers together with the form data.

Apache takes the request header "content-length", in this case 4875 bytes, it also takes the
4875 bytes long "byte stream".

Now Apache creates a new process that will eventually process the cgi data.

Apache has to hand the 4875 bytes of the cgi data over to the new process.

How is he doing this?

Is he performing inter process communication, so is Apache creating a socket to the new process??

In this case the other side, the cgi program can experience the following problem:

The CGI program gets the content length, wants to read the 4875 bytes in ONE pass, but due
to network delays gets the first time only 4300 bytes.

But if Apache does not create a socket to the new cgi process (inter process comm.), could 
it be that the cgi program also does not grab all bytes in the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that read will not return 5000 bytes due to network delays and other factors. You want to read until you read EOF, or the number of bytes read reaches 5000, or read returns an error code, by calling read in a loop for example. From the [read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) manpage:

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. **It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.** On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately. In this case it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any) changes.

Comment: "*You want to read until you read EOF ...*" or until the sum of the values returned by all call to `read()` had added up to 5000 or `read()` returned `-1`.